# In the definition of Variance, why doesn't $(x-\mu)^2$ apply to the $P(x)$ part of the definition?

Tags: statistics, functions

There are several entries on why the term $P(x)$ is included when defining the expected value, $E(x)=\sum_x xP(x)$ or variance $E(x-\mu)^2$. I understand that the term $P(x)$ gives the weighting of a given $X=x$ in the sample space.  My question is somewhat different.  It   involves the definition of variance $E\left(x-\mu\right)^2$ and its expansion to $\sum_x(x-\mu)^2 P(x)$ .

When $\left(x-\mu\right)^2$ is substituted for $x$ in $E(x)$, why doesn't this substitution apply to the sum's index $\sum_x$ and the probability function $P(x)$? That is why wouldn't the result of $E(x-\mu)^2$ be: $$E(x-\mu)^2=\sum_{(x-\mu)^2}(x-\mu)^2P(x-\mu)^2$$ On the one hand, it would seem to me, that this is what would result from a substitution in a normal algebraic function. On the other, I realize that $P(x-\mu)^2$ would probably not be defined for every, or possibly any, value in the range of $(x-\mu)^2$ and that I would be hard pressed to define $(x-\mu)^2$ as an index.

What I am trying to understand in the situation above is when is it permitted to ignore the substitution of $x$ in a function and how is it justified.

Hope I have been clear enough in my question.

Mark

Answer (score 1):

Assuming we are dealing with a discrete distribution, and a little less ambiguity in your notation, what you suggest is certainly possible

So for the mean of a random variable $X$, you can write $$\mathbb{E}[X]=\sum_xx \mathbb{P}(X=x)$$

For the variance you can write $$\mathbb{E}[(X-\mu)^2]=\sum_x (x-\mu)^2 \mathbb{P}(X=x)$$ but you can also write $$\mathbb{E}[(X-\mu)^2]=\sum_y y \mathbb{P}((X-\mu)^2=y)$$

Take for example $X$ taking the values $0,1,2$ each with probability $\frac13$.  Then $\mu=1$ and so $(X-\mu)^2$ can take the values $0$ with probability $\frac13$ and $1$ with probability $\frac23$.  So you can calculate the variance as $(0-1)^2\times \frac13+(1-1)^2\times \frac13+(2-1)^2\times \frac13=\frac23 $ or as $0\times \frac13+1\times \frac23 = \frac23$, both giving the same result

Comment: @Mark: You may be interested in [the Law of the Unconscious Statistician,](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_the_unconscious_statistician) which deals with your problem in greater generality.